# NSString rangeOfString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, indexing

How do I find the actual index of the string searched for using `rangeOfString`? So I have this:

`[name rangeOfString: @"Arnold"];`

How do I retrieve the index of the string's location? I need both the beginning index and the index where the string ends. Example would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSRange range = [name rangeOfString: @"Arnold"];
NSUInteger start = range.location;
NSUInteger end = start + range.length;
```

Answer (score 4):

`-[NSString rangeOfString:]` returns an `NSRange` struct which has two items: `location`, which tells you the index of the search string, and `length`, which tells you the length. So:

```
[name rangeOfString:@"Arnold"].location
```

gives you the index where the string `Arnold` occurs in `name`.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to store the result, do I use an `NSRange` variable?